# ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: android

I'm android beginner, delete image file from mipmap and then it show error.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxKqt.png)

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/home/nk/Android/Sdk/build-tools/24.0.0/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

how to reslove it. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recommended to **Clean & Rebuild** the project once you delete anything from resources.

Comment: @Neeraj, If you feel this answer helped solved your issue, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This will help the community to keep the focus on unanswered questions.